# SQL Row into Columns without Pivot function

Tags: sql, row, line

I am struggling with this easy looking problem, when I want to transform rows for one id into columns. So there would be X in column , if that ID has row with that value but without using PIVOT as I am not on 11g, so it needs to be some ancient way :) If that is possible as I believe is just not able to crack it on my own. Thank you for help whoever likes challenges and think is easy as it looks like, but is not :/

So if I have

```
ID Access DB1 DB2 DC1
1  DB1    x 0 0
1  DB2    0 0 0
1  DC1    0 0 x
2  DB1    x 0 0
2  DB2    0 x 0
3  DC1    0 0 x
```

So the result what I am looking for will be just 3 Rows

```
ID DB1 DB2 DC1
1  x   0  x
2  x   x  0
3  0   0  x
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1338592

I am wondering I wouldn't have these 3 other columns and have just first two. What would be the way transform rows into columns. First if there would be exact number so in our case 3 columns DB1, DB2 and DC1 and what if the number wouldn't be know so all distinct row will create new columns. Anybody for challenge.

Input 1

```
ID Access
1 DB1 
1 DB2 
1 DC1 
2 DB1 
2 DB2 
3 DC1
```

Results 1

```
ID DB1 DB2 DC1 
1 DB1 DB2 DC1 
2 DB1 DB2 
3         DC1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want `max()`:

```
select id, max(db1), max(db2), max(db3)
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Thank you , yes that was exactly what I needed. Knowledge is power ;)

Comment: I am wondering  what would be the way if I wouldn't have these 3 other columns and have just first two. What would be the way transform rows into columns. First if there would be exact number so in our case 3 columns DB1, DB2 and DC1 and what if the number wouldn't be know so all distinct row will create new column. Anybody for challenge.


Input 1

ID Access 

1  DB1
    
1  DB2
    
1  DC1
    
2  DB1
    
2  DB2
    
3  DC1


Results 1

ID DB1 DB2 DC1

1  DB1 DB2 DC1

2  DB1 DB2

3                   DC1

Comment: @PeterKepo . . . You should ask new questions as a new *question*, not a comment.  However, if you do not know how many columns are in the result set, you need to use dynamic SQL -- construct the SQL statement as a string in an application and then execute it.